# Node js - Cluster delay before delegating request

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

I'm using cluster module with node.js to benefit from multiple cpu cores (4 in my case). The problem is, that if a worker is busy, the next request is delegated to another available worker only after about 10 seconds, which is unacceptable. I'm using an infinite loop to test the cluster as follows:

```
var cluster = require ('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;
    for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount-1; ++i) {
        cluster.fork();
    }  
} else {
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        console.log('Served by worker %d!', cluster.worker.id);
        while(true) {}
        console.log("done");
        res.status(200).send();
    });

    app.listen(8080, function () {
        console.log('Worker %d running!', cluster.worker.id);
    }); 
}

cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {
    console.log('Worker %d died :(', worker.id);
    cluster.fork();
});
```

At first I open localhost:8080 in browser, and log message "Served by worker 1" is printed instantly. Then I open the same page in a new tab, and only after 10 seconds, the "Served by worker 2" is printed. Why is this, and how would I get the request to be delegated immediately to an available worker?

Comment: My guess is that `cluster` relies on the master and child processes to be able to communicate with each other. If you're blocking the child processes entirely with an infinite loop, that communication is effectively being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Which core runs the `load-balancer` method? Maybe the balancer is too busy because of infinite loop to send the request to the other app.

In fact a `for..loop` works synchronously and if `load-balancer` method is in the same app and core with the `loop` then the load balancer never works if there is an inifinite loop.

I strongly recommend using of [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/) to create a cluster. A library -that has been developed for years- provides much more than your expectations.

Good luck..

Comment: Thanks for the advice! However, pm2 is licensed under AGPL. Does that cause some restrictions on a commercial software? I generally prefer MIT/BSD licensed libraries.